# 3 D6 pick 2 vs 2 D6 with 1 reroll

Tags: probability, games, odds

I was wondering if there is any statistical difference between rolling three 6 sided dice and taking the best two (looking for a 7 or higher) and rolling two 6 sided dice with the option to re-roll one?

Comment: I've found that https://anydice.com/ is a nice resource for people interested in RPG-type dice probabilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the goal is to obtain 7+ eyes and there is no preference about the total score otherwise - then there is no difference between rolling 3 vs rolling 2 and re-rolling the lower one when their sum is lower than 7.

Think about it like this:

You roll 3 dice. You look at the first 2 of them. If they do not sum to 7 you look at the 3rd. But you will always want to add the 3rd to the bigger score of the first 2. There is no sense in keeping the smaller one.

This exact scenario plays out with 2 dice, except instead of discarding the lower of the two and looking at third - you re-roll the second die.

---

However if the total score matters and i.e. 9 is better than 8 then there is a difference. In this case as another answer pointed out - when you re-roll the second die you might actually get a lower number than it had before.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely there is a difference between the two. In the first case, you are guaranteed to roll three dice and ignore the lowest value. In the second case, you *can* roll three dice, but it's possible that you get stuck with the lowest value on your last roll. This die would have been ignored had you rolled all three simultaneously, as in the first case.

"Roll three-pick two" will on average yield a higher total than "roll two-reroll one". If you assume the same sequence of dice rolls tested for both strategies, "roll three-pick two" will always yield the higher total.

Comment: I think the question is not asking for a "higher average yield" but rather a goal of obtaining a "7 or higher",

Comment: Thanks for the info! So it seems like if I am looking to roll a 7 or higher, roll 3 pick 2 will on average be more advantageous than roll 2 with re-roll 1. Are there any statistical concepts I could research that cover this sort of question?

Comment: @Matt, I missed the part of your question about the specific target score. With a pre-specified target, Karolis' answer is better. If you haven't hit the target with two dice, you're forced to roll the third anyway, which then is the sole determinant of whether you hit the target. It's almost counterintuitive that rolling 3 has a higher average score, but the odds of passing a specific score is identical to roll 2 + 1.